# What is the difference between Ruby and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been studying Ruby for the past few days and I have noticed there is Ruby on Rails.

What is the difference between the two? Do they work together? Is the syntax the same?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Ruby is a programming language. Ruby on Rails ("RoR") is a web-application framework that is implemented in Ruby.

So they not only "work together" but RoR depends on Ruby.

Answer (score 22):

Ruby is a general purpose language. Ruby on Rails is a Ruby framework for implementing web applications.

Answer (score 14):

Ruby is an interpreted scripting language for quick and easy object-oriented programming.

Ruby is a programming Language

Ruby on Rails is web-development framework.

You can read more in "[Small Discussion about Ruby on Rails](http://www.queryhome.com/64676/introduction-about-ror-i-e-ruby-on-rails)".

Answer (score 10):

Just like PHP has Codeigniter , CakePHP and Laravel, similarly, Ruby has Ruby on Rails ("RoR").

Answer (score 8):

Ruby is a scripting language and Rails is a framework which is built using Ruby.

Ruby and Rails are tightly coupled and "Rails is magic emerged out of Ruby". Whatever you write in a Rails application is just Ruby code.
When you run a Rails application, you are just interpreting the Ruby code using Ruby's interpreter.

Comment: Not really "coupled". Rails is totally dependent on Ruby but it's pretty much a one-way thing. OK, cool ideas in Rails may find their way into standard libraries over time and Rails may be a driver for increased development activity on Ruby (note Engine Yard's involvement), but Rails is not necessary to Ruby's continuing existence.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby on Rails is a library written in the Ruby language. Its popularity prompted many people to take up writing in Ruby to make use of it, which led many people to treat them as inseparable. :)

Comment: I'd argue that RoR is a framework, not a library. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework for more.

Comment: @lutz: And I'd argue that you are probably right. Wait, that's not much of an argument. :o

Comment: @lutz Rack is _technically_ the framework. Oh wait, thats a library for ruby, so ruby must be the framework. I hate the library vs framework distinction.