# How are Ruby and Rails related?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all, i want some clarification :)

1) Is RoR like a server scripting language?

2) Can it be used as an alternative to php?

I started learning Ruby from The Ruby Programming Language book and haven't yet come across something which relates to the web. Is **Ruby** for **desktop apps** and **Rails** for **web apps**?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237372/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-and-ruby-on-rails/1237380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not Really. Ruby on Rails is a web application framework written in Ruby. If you need a comparison, Ruby on Rails is for Ruby what Zend Framework, CakePHP or Symfony are for PHP.
2. Neither Ruby nor Ruby on Rails are real alternatives to PHP. PHP is a programming language focused on web applications. Ruby is a pure programming language which can be used for creating web applications.

Ruby on Rails offers a more high-level approach for writing web applications with Ruby. Ruby offers some low-level CGI libraries you can use to interact with web servers, but it requires much more effort compared to PHP (because again, PHP is a web-focused language).
For this reason, almost nobody writes web application in Ruby without using a framework such as Rails, Sinatra or others.

Comment: PHP is a Scripting language, not Programming language !! just like 'ol ASP!

Comment: What is the definition of a "scripting language" and what is a "programming language" so you can claim that X is one of them, but not the other?

Comment: I disagree with your second paragraph. Ruby alone is not focused on web applications like PHP is, but Ruby with Rails is very much a real alternative to PHP.

Comment: I don't agree with you in that PHP requires less effort to learn. It's something unmeasurable - too many factors. I could say Ruby is easier to learn since it looks more like plain English than PHP (which looks more like C).

Comment: The "more effort" was related to the interaction with web server. Ruby requires more effort to work with web server because it doesn't offert built-in server/cookie/session facilities like PHP does.

Comment: @Emil Ivanov: Typically a "scripting" language is interpreted as it runs, whereas a "programming" language is compiled into an independent binary before it is run.

Comment: @bta: So this means that Java is a scripting language - it's compiled to bytecode and then ran.

Comment: PHP is a DSL for web servers.  Ruby is a general purpose language with strong metaprogramming capabilities that make it suitable for creating DSL's.  You could say that Ruby is a DSL metalanguage; RoR is an instance of a Ruby DSL.

Answer (score 9):

ruby - dynamic programming language
ruby on rails - framework for creating web apps written in ruby

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is an all-purpose scripting language. There are GUI toolkits for Ruby, sure.

Rails is a web framework implemented in Ruby, which can be used to develop web apps - as an alternative to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is a language - and one that encourages (some might say enforces) object-oriented programming.

Rails is a framework for writing applications and it uses the Ruby language - hence the term "Ruby on Rails".

Answer (score 2):

- Ruby is a general-purpose, dynamic, object-oriented scripting language
- Ruby on Rails is a web framework that's written in Ruby

Rails' ActiveSupport module also enhances Ruby in certain ways by adding capabilities to some of Ruby's built-in classes. Rails depends on Ruby, but Ruby doesn't depend on Rails.