# What's the differences between Ruby On Rails and Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Ruby and Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237372/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-and-ruby-on-rails)

What's the differences between the two?

Comment: RoR is a framework, Ruby is a language.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is the actual programming language that you code in. It is analogous to php, python or C.

Ruby on Rails is the framework for the ruby programming language that essentially organizes your ruby files, creates abstractions for generating files, and imposes specific rules for your programming to standardize and streamline the development experience. It is analogous to Django, which is a framework for python, and cakePHP, which is a framework for php.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

- Ruby is a programming language.
- Ruby On Rails is a framework using Ruby

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is a programming language, and Ruby on Rails is a framework built on Ruby, used for building web applications.

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, Ruby is a programming language, while Ruby On Rails is a web framework built using Ruby.

One important point to make is that the Ruby language is object based, and these objects are not closed, allowing the language to be extended.

Ruby On Rails uses this extensibility to add features to Ruby that enhance its use for web applications.

Comment: When you say Rails, are you refering to ROR?

Comment: RoR == Ruby on Rails, so yes, he's referring to RoR when he says Rails